# Не отправляются данные через API партнерской сети с лендинга

Tags: javascript, api, post, form, get

Такая проблема, есть лендинг в нём такой API
перед DOCTYPE

```
    <?php if (!empty($_POST['phone'])) {
        send_the_order ($_POST);
    }
    function send_the_order ($post){
        $params=array(
    'flow_hash' => $post['flow_hash'],
    'landing' => $post['landing'],
    'referrer' => $post['referrer'],
    'phone' => $post['phone'],
    'name' => $post['name'],
    'country' => $post['country'],
    'address' => $post['address'],
    'email' => $post['email'],
    'lastname' => $post['lastname'],
    'comment' => $post['comment'],
    'layer' => $post['layer'],
    'sub1' => $post['sub1'],
    'sub2' => $post['sub2'],
    'sub3' => $post['sub3'],
    'sub4' => $post['sub4'],
    'sub5' => $post['sub5'],
    'link_redirect' => $post['link_redirect']
    );
    $url = 'http://site.com/api/new-order/';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    $return= curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $array=json_decode($return, true);
    header('Location: Thanks.php');
    }
    ?>
```

у меня происходит редирект с трекера на лендинг, в url лендинга указываются значения get
(надеюсь я правильно говорю, чтобы никого не запутать, сам только-только начинаю разрабатывать)

значения такие site.com/?sub1={цифры1}&sub2={цифры2}&sub3={цифры3}&sub4={цифры4}&sub5={цифры5}

мне нужно передать их с формой
что мне нужно вставить в форму чтобы данные из url например sub1 передался
в 
форма у меня динамическая через js
пока что код не буду кидать, попробовать разобраться через одну из динамических форм вот такую

```
<form class="order_form" action="" method="POST"> 
<select class="country_select wheel_input" name="country">
<option value="gr">Ελλάδα</option>
<option value="cy">Κύπρος</option>
</select>
<div style="display: none">
<input type="hidden" name="ip" value="<?=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']?/>">
<input type="hidden" name="createdAt" value="<?=date(" y-m-d="" h:i:s")?="">"&gt;
<input type="hidden" name="userAgent" value="<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']?>">
<input type="hidden" name="flow_hash" value="ZVik">
<input type="hidden" name="sub1" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="sub2" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="sub3" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="sub4" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="sub5" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="referrer" value="<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']?>">
</div> 
<label for="name" class="data_label">Εισαγάγετε ένα όνομα</label>
<input class="wheel_input" type="text" name="name" required="" id="name" placeholder="Πλήρες όνομα"><label for="phone" class="data_label">Εισαγάγετε το τηλέφωνο</label> 
<input class="wheel_input" type="text" id="phone" name="phone" required="" placeholder="Τηλέφωνο"> 
<input type="hidden" name="landing" value="blognevs.com/gr/ketodiet/108/"> 
<button class="main-link" type="submit">Αγορά με έκπτωση 50%!</button> 
</form>
```

Это скопировано из просмотра кода, так как он склеивается из нескольких js структур
Получается мне в Sub1 формы нужно переносить код из url

UPD:

```
formApi: {
        isNeeded: 1, 
        landingValue: '',
        countryName: 'Ελλάδα', 
        flowHash: 'ZVik', 
        priceMain: 29, 
        currencyMain: 'EUR', 
        sub1: ''
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="hidden" name="sub1" value="<?=$_GET['sub1'];?>">
<input type="hidden" name="sub2" value="<?=$_GET['sub2'];?>">
<input type="hidden" name="sub3" value="<?=$_GET['sub3'];?>">
<input type="hidden" name="sub4" value="<?=$_GET['sub4'];?>">
<input type="hidden" name="sub5" value="<?=$_GET['sub5'];?>">
```

Comment: Удивлен, что меня поняли, ох думал не найду ответа, благодарю)) А такой вопрос, если у меня динамическая форма на javascript и мне нужно из лендинга подхватить настройки для формы в js файл 
в ленде после body такой script настройки для формы (дополнил вопрос)
как вставить, в sub1 так же или есть более правильное решение?